# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that only non-zero partial derivatives of degree less or equal than 4

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^5$ funtion such that only non-zero partial derivatives of degree less or equal than 4 at that point $\mathrm(0,0)$ are $\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^4}\mathrm(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}\mathrm(0,0)$. It's also known that:
> $\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^4}\mathrm(0,0)\left(\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^4}\mathrm(0,0)+6\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}\mathrm(0,0)\right) < \mathrm 0.$ How to show that $ \mathrm(0,0)$ is a saddle point?

It could be shown that these two partial derivatives have opposite signs and considering $\operatorname{g}(x)=f(x,\mathrm 0)$, we have $\operatorname{g}(x)=\operatorname{g}(0)+\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^4}\mathrm(0,0)\mathit x^4 +\mathit o(x^5)$, concluding that $\operatorname{g}(x) < \operatorname{g}(0)$ or that $\operatorname{g}(x)>
\operatorname{g}(0)$ based upon the sign of $\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^4}$. How should we use the other partial derivative in order to prove that$ \mathrm(0,0)$ is a saddle point?

Comment: Consider $f(x,x).$

Comment: How should one derive its associated Taylor's Formula?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions $$f(x,y)=f(0,0)+\frac1{24}\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^4}(0,0)x^4+\frac14\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}(0,0)x^2y^2+o((x^2+y^2)^2).$$

Comment: Sorry, would $\operatorname{f}\mathrm (x,x) -\operatorname{f}\mathrm (0,0)$=$\frac{1}{4!}$ ($\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^4}\mathrm(0,0)+6\frac{\partial^4 f }{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}\mathrm(0,0)$)$\mathrm{x^4}$+$\mathrm o((x^4) $ be correct?

Comment: Of course: it is the particular case $y=x$ of Taylor's formula given above.